# Drools Rule Engine: Is it possible to have a params be a list and you run the condition for each value in the list in a Decision table?

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I am trying to create a rules engine via a decision table. I want to run a rule on each value in a given list.

For example, I have the following condition column:

[image: Decision Table Column Picture]

I am trying to follow the following snippet from section 6.1.4.3 from

[docs](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch06.html#d0e6792)

where it states:

> A text according to the pattern forall(delimiter){snippet} is expanded by repeating the snippet once for each of the values of the comma-separated list of values in each of the cells below, inserting the value in place of the symbol $ and by joining these expansions by the given delimiter. Note that the forall construct may be surrounded by other text.

However when I try the above snippet condition, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while creating KieBase[Message [id=1, kieBase=rules, level=ERROR, path=rules_for_jpmc.xls, line=7, column=0
   text=[ERR 102] Line 7:123 mismatched input 'param' in rule "Green Scenario 1.2"], Message [id=2, kieBase=rules, level=ERROR, path=rules_for_jpmc.xls, line=0, column=0
   text=Parser returned a null Package]]
```

I just want to run `productCurrent == $param` on both pizza and calzone, and if one is met, the condition is true, without having to use $1, $2, etc. Is there a pattern on how to run a condition on a paramater list?

Comment: Please add more info for a better understanding of the question. Add sample java Object and actual rule. Based on the error I can only say that the DRL parser is not able to get 'param' variable. \

Comment: You have example right there in 6.1.4.4: 
```Example 6.1. Interpolating cell data

If the template is Foo(bar == $param) and the cell is 42, then the result is Foo(bar == 42).

If the template is Foo(bar < $1, baz == $2) and the cell contains 42,43, the result will be Foo(bar < 42, baz ==43).

The template forall(&&){bar != $} with a cell containing 42,43 results in bar != 42 && bar != 43.```

The delimiter is binary logic operator which shloud be used, not value delimiter, i believe that values are always separated by , (comma).